# Найти соответствие сроки из одного датафрейма с графой по нескольким строкам другого датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дана задача найти соответствие оплаты накладных в графе DocN df1 с данными графе TXT в df2.
Вывести на печать накладную (DocN) + сумму(DocSum) и реквизиты соответствующей ей оплаты (DocP, Date)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
data1 = {
"DocN": ['140111038-001', '7314560', '169233301-001','ЕКТ01886853','ЕКТ02126350','30262-19', 
'27283-19','746'],
"DocSum": ['358,80', '1487,45', '7458,78','2478,12','9624,95','3247,32', 
'3224,25','32587,22'],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
"TXT": ['Оплата за товар по сч-ф 30262-19, 30317-19, 30329-19, 31270-19, 32038-19, 26713-19, 
26715-19, ', 'Оплата за товар по сч-ф 26721-19, 26748-19, 29835-19, 31112-19, 26746-19, 30041- 
19, 23150-19, ', 'Оплата за товар по сч-ф 23525-19, 25050-19, 26244-19, 27997-19, 28032-19, 
30278-19, ЕКТ01886853','Оплата за товар по сч-ф 29227-19, 29713-19, 27283-19, 32003-19, 29235- 
19, 29888-19, 7314560','Оплата за товар по сч-ф 175634096-001, 175634109-001, 175623281-001, 
175638863-001, 140111038-001'],
"DocP": [112, 113, 114, 115, 116],
"Date": ["25.01.2022", "26.01.2022", "27.01.2022", "28.01.2022", "29.01.2022"]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

я очистил данные в df2

```
for i in range(0,len(df2)):
  txt_list = df2.loc[i,'TXT'].replace(",","").split()
  print(txt_list)
```

далее планировал создать вложенный цикл, который бы брал номер накладной и сличал со списком txt_list по каждой строке последовательно

```
for i in range(0,len(df2)):
  txt_list = df2.loc[i,'TXT'].replace(",","").split()    
  for m in df1['DocN']:
    if m in txt_list:
```

но данные формируются некорректно

Answer (score 1):

могу такой вариант предложить:

```
df1.join(df1.DocN.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(df2.loc[df2['TXT'].str.contains(fr'\b{x}\b'),['DocP','Date']]
                        .to_dict('list'))))

>>>
'''
            DocN    DocSum        DocP                      Date
0  140111038-001    358,80  [112, 116]  [25.01.2022, 29.01.2022]  <--- немного изменил data2 для тестирования
1        7314560   1487,45       [115]              [28.01.2022]
2  169233301-001   7458,78          []                        []
3    ЕКТ01886853   2478,12       [114]              [27.01.2022]
4    ЕКТ02126350   9624,95          []                        []
5       30262-19   3247,32       [112]              [25.01.2022]
6       27283-19   3224,25       [115]              [28.01.2022]
7            746  32587,22          []                        []
```

Comment: Спасибо за хороший вариант! Полезный)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый. можете даже "плюс" поставить.

Comment: Сейчас увидел что в выводе по 7 индексу строки в значении DocN "746" не относится к  DocP "113" ошибочно попало из-за наличия в TXT "26746-19" содержащего "746"

Comment: @user534280, да, похоже без регулярки тут не обойтись, поправил шаблон, попробуйте теперь

Comment: Да, сейчас все успешно!)

Comment: добрый день, @SergFSM . Я вернулся к вашему коду и у меня вопрос по нему. Если я захочу добавить отбор помимо в графе DocN df1 с данными графе TXT в df2 еще по дополнительной графе DocArt в df1 и графе DocArtP в df2 с условием равенства я применяю `df1.join(df1.DocN.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(df2.loc[df2['TXT'].str.contains(fr'\b{x}\b')& df1['DocArt'] == df2['DocArtP'],['DocP','Date']]
                        .to_dict('list'))))`
как корректно применить условие по равенству?